# React Hooks not changing object state until I scroll the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new with React, and I'm having a problem rendering a component ("setBoard" don't take effect until I scroll the page):

```
function GameManager() {
  const [board, setBoard] = useState(new Board)

const handleKeyDown = useCallback(event => {
if (board.hasWon()) {
  return;
}
if (event.keyCode >= 37 && event.keyCode <= 40) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var direction = event.keyCode - 37;
  setBoard(board.move(direction))
}
  }, [])

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
  return() => {window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)}

}, [handleKeyDown])
return (
  // <div onTouchStart={this.handleTouchStart.bind(this)} onTouchEnd={this.handleTouchEnd.bind(this)}>
  <div>
            <div class="heading" >
        <button class="restart-button" onClick={restartGame} onTouchEnd={restartGame}>New Game</button>
        < Score score={board.score} />
            </div>
        <BoardView board={board} />
      </div>
    );
}
```

My component was not re rendering, but the values of object "board" were changing:

```
return( </div>    <BoardView board={board} /> </div>)
```

After some research, I found that React compares if the object has changed with Object.is, and the response is true, maybe because how I coded "board":

```
  Board.prototype.move = function (direction) {
    // 0 -> left, 1 -> up, 2 -> right, 3 -> down
    this.clearOldTiles();
    for (var i = 0; i < direction; ++i) {
      this.cells = rotateLeft(this.cells);
    }
    var hasChanged = this.moveLeft();
    for (var i = direction; i < 4; ++i) {
      this.cells = rotateLeft(this.cells);
    }
    if (hasChanged) {
      this.addRandomTile();
    }
    this.setPositions();
    return this;
  };
```

Maybe I should return something different than "return this" in .move()??

Any ideas??? (:

Thanks for reading!

EDIT:

Now is working, but I'm not sure if it was the best approach:

Changed the props in the component, instead of all the object:

```
<BoardView boardTiles={board.tiles} boardCells={board.cells} />
```

Now, it should update when board.tiles or board.cells changes.

Also change the way I set the object state (vars separately)

```
board.move(direction)
      setBoard(prevBoard => ({...prevBoard, tiles: board.tiles, cells: board.cells, score: board.score}))
```

Is this way efficient? can be optimized?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add other relatives parts of your code (`setPositions`, `BoardView` etc..) either a sandbox with same behavio, because right now it bit impossible to point on the specific line that cause your issue

Comment: Thanks Hagai, I added more code, should I add all Board object? I try to keep it simple